# Increment text in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, auto-increment

I am trying to perform this pseudo-code, but can't seem to succeed with my limited knowledge of javascript/jquery..

`for i = 0; i < 60; i++
{`
`<p>This is person *i*</p>}`

This will then create 60 HTML lines saying This person is... and its respective number.
I have made a program in VB.NET writing out this code for me, but it makes the HTML document very large.
Is it possible to have these lines displayed without the really written in the file?

Comment: Could you please re-phrase your question as it's difficult to understand

Comment: If you're creating elements in Javascript, you have to append them to a parent.

Comment: any backend code you use will generate html which will be sent off to the browser.  I wouldn't be overly concerned about the size of your generated html, unless it starts breaking into the hundreds of thousands of lines.

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript you would want to do something like:

```
for( i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    document.write("<p>This is person "+i+"</p>");
}
```

Note that you want do call this while the page is loading (place the `<script>` in where you would want these elements to be), `document.write` will clear the DOM if it already finished loading. Otherwise you would add this into some container like so:

```
for( i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
    document.getElementById("myContainer").innerHTML += "<p>This is person "+i+"</p>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should look like this in Html/javascript:

```
<script>
for(i = 0; i < 60; i++){
    document.write("<p>This is person "+i+"</p>"); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var contents = [];
            for (var i=0;i<600;i++) {
                contents.push("This is person " + i);
            }
            $("#content").html(contents.join("<br/>"))
        });
```

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to use a data binding library like [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/). This will greatly reduce the amount of HTML & Javascript you have to write.

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('Main', ['$scope', function($scope){
   $scope.numOfP = [1,2,3];
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="app">
 <div ng-controller="Main">
  <p ng-repeat="p in numOfP track by $index">This is person {{ $index }}</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

This will repeat your block of HTML for the give number of array elements in `numOfP`.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mg89Love/)